# Uncaught Error: Class ‘WP_Upgrader_Skin’ not found

Tags: php, wp-cli

WP-CLI 2.9.0 run with –debug

```
….
Debug (bootstrap): argv: /bin/wp core check-update –debug –path=/home/web/public_html (0.752s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /home/web/public_html/ (0.752s)
Debug (hooks): Executing hook: before_wp_load (0.752s)
Debug (context): Using context ‘cli’ (0.753s)
Debug (bootstrap): Begin WordPress load (0.753s)
Debug (bootstrap): wp-config.php path: /home/web/public_html/wp-config.php (0.753s)
Debug (bootstrap): Looking for UTF-8 BOM (0.753s)
Debug (bootstrap): Looking for UTF-16 (BE) BOM (0.753s)
Debug (bootstrap): Looking for UTF-16 (LE) BOM (0.753s)
Debug (hooks): Executing hook: after_wp_config_load (0.754s)
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Upgrader_Skin' not found in phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/UpgraderSkin.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#1 phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
#4 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(650): unserialize()
#5 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/option.php(253): maybe_unserialize()
#6 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/cron.php(1183): get_option()
#7 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/cron.php(765): _get_cron_array()
#8 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/cron.php(817): wp_get_scheduled_event()
#9 /home/web/public_html/wp-content/plugins/worker/init.php(723): wp_next_scheduled()
#10 /home/web/public_html/wp-content/plugins/worker/init.php(761): mwp_init()
#11 /home/web/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/0-worker.php in phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/UpgraderSkin.php on line 13
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Upgrader_Skin' not found in phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/UpgraderSkin.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#1 phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
#4 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(650): unserialize()
#5 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/option.php(253): maybe_unserialize()
#6 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/cron.php(1183): get_option()
#7 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/cron.php(765): _get_cron_array()
#8 /home/web/public_html/wp-includes/cron.php(817): wp_get_scheduled_event()
#9 /home/web/public_html/wp-content/plugins/worker/init.php(723): wp_next_scheduled()
#10 /home/web/public_html/wp-content/plugins/worker/init.php(761): mwp_init()
#11 /home/web/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/0-worker.php in phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/UpgraderSkin.php on line 13
Error: There has been a critical error on this website. Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
```

I suspect there could be a conflict with plugins but I’m unsure how to identify or resolve this error.

Anybody got error message like this?